# Visual Studio Reports (RDLC) -two page orientations in one report?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, report, orientation, rdlc, report-designer

I am using Visual Studio Report Designer to design invoices.

My company's invoices need to be printed with the **first page portrait, and the rest of the pages landscape.**
Is there a way to do this using the report designer?

I've only been able to change the page orientation of the whole report. 
What I need is different page orientations for different sections.